# Best approach to use two different models simultaneously in the same Ruby on Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working on a web application and I have a blog page, with two controllers, a posts controller for the blog and then a subscribers controller that simply allows the user to add a new subscriber. So currently I render the content using a view defined in posts, and then within that I have a partial, _subscriber, to handle the subscription model.

The problem comes when the user tries to subscribe. I want to be able to render the new action to show validations, like this:

```rb
    def create
        @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
        if @subscriber.save
            flash[:success] = "Thank you for subscribing!"
            redirect_to subscribers_url
        else
            render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end
```

Besides the fact that this results in a duplicate view (new.html.erb is identical to the partial), because it is not a partial view, it reloads the entire page and now replaces all of the post with just the subscription form. Currently, my workaround is to do a redirect when the user clicks the button, but then validation errors don't show and it isn't really an ideal solution.

I tried just rendering the partial, instead of the :new action, like this:

```rb
render partial: 'subscriber', status: :unprocessable_entity
```

But has the same effect as just calling redirect; my validation errors won't show.

Perhaps the ideal solution is to use something like AJAX. I tried to understand Turbo Frames and Turbo Streams, but I'm a little confused how I would implement that in this situation. Essentially, I could wrap the subscribe section of my posts page in a turbo frame but then how would I update the turbo frame? I don't want to have a different post page because that wouldn't make sense. I only want to change the content of the view inside.

What would the correct/best practices way of implementing this functionality be? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to actually reload the page, then yes, you'll need to do something with either AJAX / UJS or Turbo frames.

- [My favorite AJAX / UJS tutorial](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/)
- [A good Turbo tutorial](https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails/turbo-drive)

(Or go to the dark side with React or Node or some other JS solution)